# How to edit errors instantaneously in TEX

Tags: errors, terminal-output

I would like to know how to edit the errors indicated by the TEX compiler *instataneously*
using the `i` option as said in [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Errors_and_Warnings).I know that there would be no error if you edit the file and replace `^i` with `\hat{i}`.But I would like to know if we can rectify the error without editing the file to be compiled.While running a text file using the TEX compiler I've got an error like this after trying the `i` option:

```
Z:\>latex first.txt
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX) (preloaded
 format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./first.txt
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(d:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(d:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./first.aux)
LaTeX Warning: Command \^ invalid in math mode on input line 6.
LaTeX Warning: Command \^ invalid in math mode on input line 6.
! Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode.
\add@accent ...@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent
                                                  #1 #2\egroup \spacefactor ...
l.6 $\^i
        $
? i$\hat{i}$
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   $
l.6 $\^i
        $
?
```

Could anyone tell me is it possible to rectify the error using the `i` option in the terminal(command prompt) and how to rectify the error.

Comment: Not every error can be corrected with the `i`-answer. You can replace undefined commands like in the answer of giordano, but in many cases you are simply to late. Inserting something doesn't recover from the error.

Comment: TeX is in the middle of the expansion of `\^` when the error is raised. There's no sensible way for recovering via insertion of tokens without getting other errors later on.

Comment: @egreg:Are you telling that it might not be possible to rectify the error using tokens?But as I have written in the answer I replaced the entire line with $hat{i}$ and then I got the output file.The only thing I felt complex with this method is that each time you would have to insert a line for each error.But for beginners it might be a good way to find out the errors.

Comment: You got an output (you would also without inserting anything) and errors.

Comment: @egreg:Do you mean that the input file is not really edited?That's true.But you can edit with the e option.I can't get what you meant by getting "errors" because I really got no errors but just an output file.Did you mean any other error?My intention was to print i with the hat symbol but since it was math mode compiler told you can't place such a symbol(^),so at the compile time itself I replaced it with `$\hat{i}$`.

Comment: If I have a document containing only `$\^i$` and at the error I type `i$\hat{i}$`, I get several other errors. The output has a Gamma superimposed to an italic i with a hat accent; then 94 follows, a space and a dotless i.

Comment: @egreg:Sorry for not holding your statement since you were really right in what you told.I just got the output(print i with hat symbol) accidentally by pressing the `enter` key after executing the code:`latex first.txt`.So could you tell me why I got the output like that just by pressing an `enter` key and without inserting anything.Let me also tell you that even if you don't press `enter` key you would still get the output.Does this mean that the Tex compiler corrected the error?Could you help me.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand.

Comment: @egreg:I meant to say that what you told was correct that's why I upvoted it.So could you tell me why while (I pressed enter or even without pressing enter) I got the output(printing i with hat symbol) by **after** inserting the `i` option.I would like to know whether the tex compiler automatically corrected the error.

Comment: @justin TeX tries to recover from errors; adding tokens with `i` can help sometimes to bring it into synch and avoiding other errors (but the source should be edited afterwards anyway). In this case there's not much one can do except fixing the error in the source file. You indeed get `î`, but it doesn't mean you should ignore the error. By the way, you should use `\hat{\imath}` in order to remove the dot.

Comment: @egreg:Okay.But I couldn't get what you meant by:"TeX is in the middle of the expansion of `\^` when the error is raised" in previous comment.Does that mean tex takes each character as a token.For example in `$\^i$` are the tokens present are:$,\,^.i,$?Also why couldn't the tex compiler replace `$\^i$` with `$\hat{i}$` after pressing the i option(insert).I would like to know that if Tex compiler is looking token by token then we should definitely have place to replace the statement(`$\^i$`) isn't it?Could you help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after <kbd>i</kbd> (but what you've tried works for me), and the insert the correction:

```
$ cat foo.tex 
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\LaTEX
\end{document}
$ pdflatex foo.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 8 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./foo.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \LaTEX

? i
insert>\LaTeX
[1{/home/user/.texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./foo.aux) )
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/s
hare/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb>
Output written on foo.pdf (1 page, 16374 bytes).
Transcript written on foo.log.
```

But you should consider editing the source with <kbd>e</kbd>, otherwise the next time you'll run into the same error.

Comment: :Yes I have done as you said but it still prints the same error.Since I'm using Windows should I do anything else?While pressing the key e it says `I cannot find emacs in the PATH`.